# Offering a freemium plugin (a free version + paid version)

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, premium

I am developing a super-awesome plugin for WordPress. I'd like to offer a free version and a paid version.

As far as I am concered, and please correct me if I am wrong, it is not allowed to host "paid software" on the WordPress Plugin Repo, even though parts of it is free. So if I am going to offer "premium features" I have to seperate this code, and make sure it is not hosted on the WordPress repo - right?

I have been removed from the WordPress repo a few years ago because of this, but I am not sure if it has changed.

The questions:

1) what would be the best option to do this? While also taking care of plugin updates?
2) Is it allowed for me to host the premium code inside the WordPress plugin repo, and then simply add a "license" page, where, if people have a valid license, it opens up all the features of my plugin?

I have seen plugins like Advanced Custom Fields, if you put in a correct license, it also allows for updating the plugin through the "Plugins" section of the site. How do they achieve this? Is there some tutorial I can follow?

Comment: 1) since it's a solved problem, I'd find a few and see what they do? e.g. [this library](https://w-shadow.com/blog/2010/09/02/automatic-updates-for-any-plugin/) uses its own scheduled job I think, or you could - with a bit of care - hook pre_set_site_transient_update_plugins to use WordPress's schedule (note that it's set at both the start and end of wp_update_plugins).

Comment: 2) you'd have to ask them I'd think.

Comment: The answer to 2 is no. You cannot have anything that requires a code or payment to unlock.